# How to take mean of dataframe columns based on intervals in one columns?

Tags: python, dataframe, mean

I have a dataframe with two columns 'True' and 'Pred'. The 'True' column has values between 65 to 90. I want to take the mean for both columns based on an interval in the 'True' column ranging between 65 to 70, 71 to 75, 76 to 80, 81 to 85, and 86 to 90. So my final dataframe should have five values in the True Column and five values in Pred Columns.

What is the easy way to do this in python? I  have given the data and the output which is required with this query.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) with [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "TRUE": [65, 67, 69, 71, 73, 75, 77, 79, 81, 83, 85, 87, 89, 90],
    "Pred": [65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 86]
})

df.groupby(pd.cut(df["TRUE"], bins=[65-1e-10, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90], labels=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]))["Pred"].mean().round(2)
```

Output:

```
     TRUE
0    66.00
1    69.00
2    71.50
3    74.00
4    79.67
Name: Pred, dtype: float64
```

`pd.cut` segements your data into categories (defined by the `labels` argument) according to bins. If you, for instance, consider the first two values of your `bins` argument, `[65-1e-10, 70, ..]` all `TRUE` values that are in that interval `(65-1e-10, 70]` (left-open, right-closed) are mapped to `0`. This series can then be used in the `groupby` statement to aggregate the segments by their means.

You can also make the intervall left-closed and right-open:

```py
df.groupby(pd.cut(df["TRUE"], bins=[65, 71, 76, 81, 86, 91], labels=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], right=False, include_lowest=True))[["TRUE", "Pred"]].mean().round(2).rename_axis(None, axis=0)
```

Output:

```
    TRUE    Pred
0   67.00   66.00
1   73.00   69.00
2   78.00   71.50
3   83.00   74.00
4   88.67   79.67
```

Comment: Why did you use "65-1e-10"? Also, can get mean and std at the same time?

Comment: @ankushjamthikar, because the interval is left-open. If you just go with 65 you will exclude it. Therefore, to include 65, you have to specify a number slightly smaller than 65, like `65-delta`. The documentation will tell you more, I have linked it.

Comment: Okay, so if we specify include_lowest=True, then there is no need to specify 65-1e-10. Right?

Comment: @ankushjamthikar, I updated my answer but yeah, depending on your intervalls, you can use the arguments.